# Reproducing the Tumblr Tagging Effect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, core-animation

I'm completely stumped as to how to do it.

First, the view looks something like this:
[image: Starting Image]

Next, you tap in the tags bar (I assume it is a modified UITextField with a placeholder image) and the tags bar animates to the top of the view. As seen in the photo below:
[image: Tags Tapped Image]

You can add a tag by typing a word or series of words and clicking return on the keyboard. Once you do this, a bubble encompasses the tag and it also shows up on the tag bar.

Once you have finished, you clicked the "Done" button and the tags bar animates downward to its original position, along with the tags in the bar, as shown below:
[image: Final Position Image]

I have several questions:

1. How do I animate the tags bar and tags field downward, and how to do animate the tags field upward (I assume with CoreAnimation - but I have no experience with it. Do I group the views together to do this, or do it one-by-one)
2. How would I produce this "tagging affect" in the UITextView/Field?

My one theory is to group the bottom two views together as a UIView, and animate that as a whole. Then for the tagging process, don't do bubbles (I would have no idea on how to do this), but just allow single-word tags and parse the textview and insert the words manually into the bar. I think this may produce a bit of a lagging affect though.

Comment: Why did you tag your question both Mono Touch and Objecive-C? (Tumblr tag removed since you are trying to copy a part of their app, not user their API)

Comment: Because I have no preference on the solution type. I personally use Xamarin's tooling, but I don't mind an Obj-C answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished creating a pretty versatile class that should do what you need. You can find it here: [RoleModel/RMSTokenView](https://github.com/RoleModel/RMSTokenView).

Comment: You might want to mention here, that it's MIT licensed.

Comment: I'll add it to the repository README. Thanks!

Comment: Just took a look at this! It will work great for my needs. Because you have it licensed as MIT, I will also create a Xamarin binding for it (link later).

Comment: If you do end up using it in an app, please let me know so that I can be inspired to do more :-).

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo, see? It's working already, that license might just be one of the best features of your project. ;-P

Answer (score 2):

from the looks of their layout, the tag graphic and settings button containing the tag are housed in one UIView (let's refer to this as `@property UIView* tagsView`), and then there is a special view that has a UITextView, over which they are placing special UIView objects with rounded corners (possibly with .cornerRadius set as provided via Quartz) that have the text of each accepted tag in them (let's call the container for this `@property UIView* tagsEditorView`).

then, to answer the question regarding animating the tags bar and the tag field upward in order to add/edit tags (or downward upon pressing done), the simplest way to do this would be use UIView class methods for animation.

```
    CGFlot keyboardTop = y; // calculate keyboard top here.
    newTagsFrame = CGFrameMake(0, 0, _tagsView.size.width, _tagsView.size.height);
    newTagsEditorFrame = CGFrameMake(0, _tagsView.size.height, _tagsView.size.width, keyboardTop);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                        _tagsView.frame = newTagsFrame;
                        _tagsEditorView.frame = newTagsEditorFrame;
                     }];
```

to answer the second question, for the shape, as mentioned above, if you `#import <QuartzCore/QuarzCore.h>`, you can set the cornerRadius and shape the items as you want.  and for the items themselves, you should just be able to add them as `UIButton` objects (or `UILabel` objects if you prefer) as subviews of tagsEditorView, positioned as you see fit.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// ...

    // at the point at which it is determined that a tag is valid, non-duplicated, etc.
    UILabel* tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    // set the label text, background color, text color, borders, frame size, etc
    // at the point at which it is determined that a tag is valid, non-duplicated, etc.
    tagLabel.layer.cornerRadius = (tagButton.frame.size.height / 2);

    _tagsArray = [_tagsArray.mutableCopy append:tagLabel];

    [_tagsEditorView addSubview:tagLabel];

// ...

    // at the point of ultimate display
    for (UILabel* tagLabel in _tagsArray)
    {
        // the following will give an initial rect to work with based on label contents,
        // and the font can be changed if desired by changing the minFontSize: argument
        CGRect tagLabelRect
          = [tagLabel.text sizeWithFont:[myFont fontWithSize:_myFontSize]
                            minFontSize:_myFontSize
                         actualFontSize:&actualFontSize
                               forWidth:_tagsEditorView.frame.size.width
                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        // calculate tagLabel.frame based on individual tag and on preceding
        // number of edited tags (filling/wrapping left as an exercise to reader)
    }
```

positioning the tags themselves is just math based on what you consider acceptable layout of tags in your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a UITextfield based solution, here is a nice open source component [JSTokenField](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField) available

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this open source project [TURecipientBar](https://github.com/davbeck/TURecipientBar). 
It look like Apple Mail recipients view. I didn't tested the solution but it look clean and handy.